# SuppressWarnings for: Boolean method 'methodName' is always inverted

Tags: java, android, lint, suppress-warnings, android-lint

The [list](https://gist.github.com/elevenetc/bf795f94aaf3e92169ef) of the most common SuppressWarnings annotations is so long and non-intuitive, that I am lost to find a correct annotation for warning

> Boolean method 'methodName' is always inverted

I don't want to change the method to return a negative value, since there is a logic consistency in the naming - e.g. method name is: `hasFlag(...)`.

What is the right annotation for this type of Lint Analysis warning?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")
```

You can discover these with the help of Android Studio. Expand the quick fix menu (alt+enter on my computer) and then choose one of the suppress quick fixes.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. **Thank you!** Yes, I am using `Alt+Enter`, but for some unknown reason this time Android Studio came with no suppress suggestion.

Comment: Suppress quick fixes seem to be now under the "fix" item (often the topmost), one menu level down. On some earlier version of Studio they were on the top level.

Comment: This was no where in the list of quick fixes.  This was no where in the entire list of lint warnings, which I searched through.  I don't know what the deal is, but Android Studio should have that information more easily available.